# How should I fix code where the rectangle I created with tkinter doesn't move with the arrow keys?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that draws a rectangle in the center of the canvas. The rectangle is supposed to get wider when the right arrow key is pressed, and narrower when the left arrow key is pressed. I seem to have the rectangle, but there is no movement.

So far, the code I have is:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, bg="#000000")
canvas.pack()
x1 = 150
y1 = 100
x2 = 250
y2 = 200

class ResizeRect:
 def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    self.x1 = x1
    self.y1 = y1
    self.x2 = x2
    self.y2 = y2
    self.rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1,1)

 def draw(self):
    canvas.delete(self.rect)
    self.rect = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                                 outline="#00B000", width=2)
 def narrower(self):
    self.x1 = self.x1 + 5
    self.x2 = self.x2 - 5
 def wider(self):
    self.x1 = self.x1 - 5
    self.x2 = self.x2 + 5

r = ResizeRect(150, 100, 250, 200)
r.draw()
def left():
   r.narrower()
def right():
   r.wider()
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', left)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', right)
```

WHen I run this code, a rectangle appears but does not move when I press the arrow keys. How can I fix this without altering my original code too much?

Comment: You're changing the `x1` and `x2` variables, but you're not redrawing the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, `left` and `right` will automatically be passed an object representing the event. You need to make sure that these functions accept this parameter even if you don't use it.

```
def left(event):
   r.narrower()
def right(event):
   r.wider()
```

Second, simply setting the coordinate won't cause the rectangle to move. You must configure the rectangle with new coordinates using the `coords` method if you want the coordinates of the actual object to change.

```
 def narrower(self):
    self.x1 = self.x1 + 5
    self.x2 = self.x2 - 5
    canvas.coords(self.rect, self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)

 def wider(self):
    self.x1 = self.x1 - 5
    self.x2 = self.x2 + 5
    canvas.coords(self.rect, self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
```